# Mock Router and Ngzone in Angular 7 Jest Unit test

Tags: jestjs, angular7, ngzone

I used ngzone and router in component class.
My unit testing was working fine but now getting error cannot read toLowerCase() of undefined.
Can anyone suggest me how to mock both Ngzone and Router.

Answer (score 2):

I use TestBed for this :)

Just configure your test module with your component and routes, then get your `Router` instance from the test module, and then you spy on `Router.navigate` to use your custom mock implementation.

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

let component: YourComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
let router: Router;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        { path: "", component: YourComponent },
        { path: "**", redirectTo: "" },
      ]),
    ],
    declarations: [YourComponent],
    providers: [],
  }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    jest
      .spyOn(router, 'navigate')
      .mockImplementation(() => of(true).toPromise());
  });
```

Comment: I can't stress enough how important the `mockImplementation` is.